# proving a claim using structural induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

hello could you check an correct me please?

we'll say that $\Sigma$ follows property "a" if for every $a,b \in \Sigma$: $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$.

1)I is a set of phrases that is defined: I consists of a single elemntary proposition p, and the only logical sign that is defined is $\Rightarrow$. show that set I is following "a" (i.e, for every $a,b \in \Sigma$: $a \Rightarrow b$ or $b \Rightarrow a$)

2)show that if $\Sigma$ follows "a", and each proposition in $\Sigma$ has a model in which it is true, then there's a model for $\Sigma$

my attempt:

1)building a building set: $a,b, b \Rightarrow a,a \Rightarrow b$we'll assume that it holds true for the base case and walk over $\lnot a$. if it follows property a, then if $a,b∈Σ: a⇒b$ or $b⇒a.$, but double contradiction we obtain it,for $\lor$ it is already defined, and in the case of $\land$, using the morgan rules and negation we can achieve the same.

regarding 2 i don't know how to prove it, but i believe it is derived using the structural induction. would appreciate your help with it.

thanank you very much for helping and correcting me.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I am confused your definition of "following a". Does it mean if $a,b\in \Sigma$ then one of $a\to b$ or $b\to a$ holds? However classical logic always proves $(a\to b)\lor (b\to a)$ is a tautology so they both can't be failed.

Comment: "phrase", "elementary phrase" ? Where did this terminology comes from ?

Comment: @HanulJeon -by "following a", i meant that  i gave the following configuration: for every $a,b∈Σ: a⇒b or b⇒a$ the name "a" and i asked how can i show that in the two questions, then given sets still follow the property "a". sorry if i was misunderstood. my main problem is with the last question. could you please help me with that?

Comment: Repeating an inadequate definition practically word-for-word does not clarify anything. You need to back up a couple of steps and give the previous definitions and facts that people need in order to see what you are talking about here.

Comment: @DavidK, i edited it and tried to use the correc terrminology and grammer. could you please check if it is clear enough? would really appreciate learning from this question